# Can I specify my executable to link to one or other library, e.g. libhello.so or libhellod.so?

Tags: c++, gcc, shared-libraries

I have my project setup such that if I do a release build then I get libraries named like `libhello.so` and if its a debug build I get names like `libhellod.so` - note the `d` on the end of the name.

So when I compile and link an application/executable I do something like:

`gcc -g -o myapp obj1 obj2 obj3 -lhellod`

Where here I am linking it to the debug library. Now I can deploy this app with its library:

- `myapp`
- `libhellod.so`

great, but then we decide that we want to produce a release version of the hello lib and deploy that with the app instead of the debug version. Now it complains that it can't find the library named `hellod`. Ok, so I can just make a symlink:

- `myapp`
- `libhello.so`
- `libhellod.so -> libhello.so`

This also works.

Can I somehow link my executable such that it will find either `libhello.so` or `libhellod.so` (without using symlinks)? - or is symlinks the only way to achieve this? or is my design just silly?!

Comment: It seems silly. You said the correct library to link is `libhello.so`, and yet you try to hack it so that linking the incorrect library, `libhellod.so`, has the same effect. Why not just link the correct library instead? You can put that in a build file so that users and developers don't have to do it manually.

Comment: @nwp I was kind of thinking that we don't need to rebuild the app, we can just re-deploy the "release" lib - which should link just as well as the debug lib (i.e. they are interchangeable (AFAIK)). What I am trying to say is I feel both libs are "the correct" one - but one has debug symbols and one does not, but the app should not care about that...? (i think)

Comment: That sounds like an [ODR](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule) disaster waiting to happen because of for example different versions of `std::string` being linked together.

Comment: @nwp ahh... that is a really good point... so, we'll go with the answer that "it is siilly" :o   If you want to add that into an answer then I will mark it up

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot.

However you might be interested in the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable. It allows you to force load a library before all others specified in the executable.

As the linker processes libraries in order, if you `LD_PRELOAD=libhellod.so yourprogram`, it should make `libhellod.so` override symbols from `libhello.so`. That won't prevent `libhello.so` from being loaded though - eg its initialization section will be run. Check the result with `LD_DEBUG=bindings`.

You can obtain the same effect editing `/etc/ld.so.preload`

Check the documentation of [ld.so](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html).

*also, just because you can does not mean it is a good design - be especially careful with functions that might get inlined and stuff like this; but if the only difference between the versions is a couple of logging and assertions you should be fine*.

Comment: That is interesting, probably not quite the direction I want to go in - but thanks for the info : )

Comment: @code_fodder, I guess, you could also remove all the `DT_NEEDED` tags requiring your libraries, and then `LD_PRELOAD` all of them for running the executable --- either debug, or release version. Read on `DT_NEEDED` if you haven't already: understanding the mechanism might help you find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to build debug executable `hellod` that links against debug `libhellod.so`.

Comment: yes.... you can rename the exe of course.... but that really is not what am asking about.